# Moving a tiled map in a jframe

Tags: java, movement, tilemap, slick, jframe

I rendered a tiled map, with the help of slick2d, in my JFrame in Java. I can move my main character, but it is just that the character itself moves. I would like to do it that, if the player moves, the map moves and the player himself stays in middle of the frame. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `JFrame`, instead use `BasicGame` subclass and `AppGameContainer` (it's much better than `JFrame`).

And to your problem, you have to create a `Camera` class. That's all already covered [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44256/how-to-add-a-scrolling-camera-to-a-2d-java-game).